# How can print Korean in UTF-8 and how to use print function properly in python?

Tags: python, printing, utf-8

I made a simple Python code like as below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print('한글', 1, '\n3')
```

the result is not that I didn't expected is following.

```
('\xed\x95\x9c\xea\xb8\x80', 1, '\n3')
```

I think the 'print()' function is never operated! how can I print without '(' and ')' ?

And also I want to print Korean properly.
How can I?

Comment: fixed the second line to

    print '한글', 1, '\n3'

Comment: the '(' and ')' were eliminated, and the printing was proper thing that I expected!

Comment: But I still don't know the reasons!

Comment: Are you using `python 2` or `python 3`?

Comment: In Python 2, `print` is a keyword, not a function.  Call without parentheses.